# How to pass a JsonPatchDocument as a property in posting object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Want to post a collection of objects where the objects have a JsonPatchDocument as a property inside it like the below code.  However, is this supported or why is the error occurring?

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DummyClass
{
    public int PriKey { get; set; }
    public JsonPatchDocument<Person> PersonPatchDocument { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Test(IEnumerable<DummyClass> input)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Trying to POST with swagger/curl and get

```json
{
  "errors": {
    "[0].PersonPatchDocument": [
      "The JSON patch document was malformed and could not be parsed."
    ]
  },
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "8000000d-0007-fd00-b63f-84710c7967bb"
}
```

Trying the following combinations and both fail with the above:

```json
[
  {
    "PriKey": 1,
    "PersonPatchDocument": {
      "ContractResolver": {
        "value": "bob",
        "path": "/name",
        "op": "replace"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

```json
[
  {
    "PriKey": 1,
    "PersonPatchDocument": {
      "value": "bob",
      "path": "/name",
      "op": "replace"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Core 2.2, but I imagine later versions have the same issue...maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON representation for a `JsonPatchDocument` is a collection of objects, rather than a single object. In your case, there's only a single change object, but it still must be wrapped as a collection. The second example is closest to what's needed, which I've included here with the change:

```json
[
  {
    "PriKey": 1,
    "PersonPatchDocument": [
      {
        "value": "bob",
        "path": "/name",
        "op": "replace"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```